# How to disable `deselect-option` in `react-select`?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, formik

I would like to use the react-select multi Select component and be able to select the same option multiple times. However, react-select does not allow one to do this. You can change the dropdown to show already selected options with `hideSelectOptions={false}`, but if you select one of them again, it will be deselected.

This issue [#3234](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3234) describes this same problem and [sugggests](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3234#issuecomment-445317191) that one way to solve this problem is to handle the `action` argument to `onChange` somehow.

Here is the solution that I attempted based off of the [suggested solution](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3234#issuecomment-445317191):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";


export default class MultiSelect extends Component<*, State> {
  handleChange(option, action) {
    console.log(option, action);
    // return;
    if (action === "deselect-option") {
      action = "select-option";
      // now how do I do the component's state?
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        isMulti
        className="basic-single"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        name="color"
        options={[{"label": "hello", "value": "hello"}, {"label": "world", "value": "world"}]}
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I expected to be able to enter "hello" multiple times but when I tried to enter "hello" again it was deleted.

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox with your current progress?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the delay. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-q5v83

Comment: It seems like all I need to do is disable this [block of code](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/Select.js#L623-L634). That's the only place where `deselect-option` is used. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Update: I got this to work a little bit: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-cu3gz

But, I get this warning when I enter multiple of the same input:
```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `hello`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

Answer (score 1):

In options, the data field makes value dynamic with any key, in this case, use Date.now() to make dynamic. then use actions 'select-option' to append to options, use actions 'remove-value'' to filter all fields in the Options data field with a label matching with selected option label and append to data and append one more object to Options datafield

```
options = [
{ value: Date.now(), label: "SUBJECT" ,val:"SUBJ" },
{ value: Date.now, label: "VERB", val:"VERB" }
]

<Select options={options} isMulti onChange={(e, option) => {
if (option.action === "select-option") {
    Options=[
    ...Options,
    {
        value: option.option.value + "_" + Date.now(),
        label: option.option.label
    }
    ];
} else if (option.action === "remove-value" ||option.action ===  "pop-value") {

    tempData = data.filter(opt => opt.label !== option.removedValue.label)
    Options=[
    ...tempData,
    {
        value: option.removedValue.value + "_" + Date.now(),
        label: option.removedValue.label
    }
    ]
}
}
} />
```

Comment: explain more about your answer. so that it can help others to understand

Comment: In options field make Value dynamic .

Comment: In options data field make value dynamic with any key, in this case, use Date.now() to make dynamic. then use actions 'select-option' to append to options, use actions 'remove-value'' to filter  the all fields in Options datafield  with label matching with selected option label and append to data  and  append one more object to Options datafield

Comment: @PrasoonDavid In the remove-value section, you're filtering to remove the object, but then you add it back? Why? that's not needed because you're deleting it, right?